# Naming issue: what name would you give to this interface?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, naming

I'm struggling with a naming issue. What name would you give to an interface that have just one method with this signature:

```
public interface ?
{
    boolean isAvailable();
}
```

Many classes in my application can implement this interface.

Comment: Just because something can be available or not means nothing. There is a design problem, if you try to write an interface that you can't give a name. You need to know what this interface means, what will you do with something, that you only know is available? You can do nothing with that, because it has no meaning.

Comment: Even though the interface is really very general  and abstract,  I still think that it means something and is useful in some way. Look at the interface `Closeable` in Java.

Comment: No, it have no meaning. Ok, let's say you implement the available method in all your objects in your code. What can you do with the information that something is available? What interaction could you take with this object, if you don't know anything about it, just that it is available?

Comment: I can, for example, not show the object in a JSF web page if it is not available. This interface will be used in a specif domain model I'm developing and it means exactly this.

Comment: You shouldn't have one interface for all objects that can have available method. You should name this interface at least as JspDataAvailabilityStatus, or even better name what type of objects is available

Comment: Just because something has a hole, it don't mean you can have sex with that. Do you catch the idea, that to much generalization is bad?

Comment: I still think that I should, because of this I can treat object uniformily without knowing how availability is implemented in each object. For one object availability can mean if the object is active, for example, for others it can mean a different thing. I can even treat leaf and composite objects uniformily. I just have to pass an object of type `Available` to some method and the method doesn't care how availability  is implemented.

Comment: Your interface is to general, it does not describe any group of objects, because all Objects can be available or not. When some programmer came after you to develop this code, you will probably need to leave your country to save your life :P just kidding... but you can make someone mad with this style of generalizing everything, belive me. It is bad just because other programmer would not know what it means, that everything could be available or not, do You catch that?

Comment: It looks like you're tying frontend logic into backend objects, which is a bad idea. Any way you look at it, this smells and there's no way I can be convinced this is a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But the objects that I'm developing in my domain model really have the notion of availability. I'm not saying that this interface will apply to everything. For example, does a class named `Name` that have firstname and surname should implemente an interface like this? I don't think so. So I do think that not all objects are candidate to implement this interface. The interface is not so general like this, but it suits the entity classes that I'm developing because they have atributes like 'active' and 'period' (a date range) that can be abstracted in `isAvailable()`.

Comment: @Davio. if you see my last comment you'll see that I'm not tying font and backend logic in objects. The concept of availability in my domain model is a concept that the frontent has to honor, not matther which frontend. It is intrinsic in the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that it really matters, you can rename it any time afterwards, and with current IDEs, it is really easy to type any name using autocomplete...

That said, if you want it short, use `Available`, if you want it more self-explanatory, use `CanBeAvailable`.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will follow this.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the word "available" already ends with "-able", I think it's okay to break with the Java interface naming convention and call it `Availability`. [Another approach, suggested in Programmers, is to use the prefix "Can-",](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131667/interface-naming-prefix-can-vs-suffix-able) in which case you can call your interface `CanBeAvailable`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Similar to @P.Péter.

Comment: Actually, @JoeydeVilla was first by a few seconds...

Comment: Yes, thank you for remind me of this, but I liked `Available` more than `Availability`. `CanBeAvailable` is very self-explanatory to me.

Answer (score 2):

The below are the standards defined for Naming conventions.

Class - Always be a **Noun**

Interface - Always be an **Adjective**

Method - should be a **verb**

So, think of some adjective which describes the purpose of your interface.